# How to use Automapper in ASP.NET Core to create mapping configuration for the following type of hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I would like to map the following hierarchy of entities to the `TestViewModel` class. I have `TestViewModel` class with the same member names and perhaps I will add more members to the view model. I am using `AutoMapper`.

```cs
public class TestProfile : Profile
{
    public TestProfile ()
    {
        CreateMap ??????              
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public List<Test1> Tests1 { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}

public class Test1
{
    public int Test1Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public List<Payload> Payloads { get; set; }        
}

public class Payload
{
    public string PayloadName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why do you even need a mapping? How does your `TestViewModel` look like?

Comment: The view model has the same hierarchy as the Test entity class.

Comment: If it has the same hierarchy then only `CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>();` should be enough to do the mapping. If that is not working for you, share `TestViewModel` (doesn't matter if it has the same hierarchy) and other (if there are any) destination models. If you already tried something that throws exception, include the complete exception message in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what your TestViewModel class looks like, and whether you also have DocumentViewModel, PayloadViewModel, etc.  Typically if you are mapping to a another set of classes that have the same naming and structure, like a set of ViewModels, you will want to have a configuration like this:

```
    public class TestProfile : Profile
    {
        public TestProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>();
            CreateMap<Test1, Test1ViewModel>();
            CreateMap<Document, DocumentViewModel>();
            CreateMap<Payload, PayloadViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

This will map all like-named properties between the two sets of classes.  If your TestViewModel shares the same child entities, then you only need the first line.

Comment: Randy, TestViewModel has the same child classes as Test class.  During mapping this exception is thrown: AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: I know how to map simple flat structures, but not child classes as shown in the above example.

Comment: @mm2, if your property names are the same, and the hierarchy is the same, then there is no need for any further specific configuration.  You only need a ```CreateMap``` for the top level (Test -> TestViewModel).  If, as you say, the TestViewModel has all the same child classes, then there is no need for mapping config for those properties.  My guess is your error means your config or profile is not getting applied for some reason.

Comment: Randy, do you mind trying to create the class hierarchies like that?